# Объяснить логику как на конкретном сайте доставются данные из бд

Tags: php, mysql

Вот есть сайт http://the-flow.ru там до дефолту 9 карт и слева и справа блоки по 4 новости. Например эти 9 карт я понимаю - например 9 последних отобразить, а слева и справа блоки по какой логике там извлекается. Можете посмотреть пожалуйста спасибо.
Можете там "больше новостей" кнопку внизу понажимать еще...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно модуль там стоит в который ты добавляешь новости которые там отображаться будут. Нужно конкретнее задавать вопрос, логику вывода каких то постов можно придумать энное количество раз.

Comment: Я руками все написал , кроме этих блоков слева и справа. Кнопка "больше новостей" load more у меня есть на js jquery ajax выводит 9 последних новостей, а блоки по 4 новости пустые, потому что я не знаю по каком принципу их выводить. Внизу страницы главной 4 блока самые популярные новости за неделю - я тоже знаю как сделать, но пока не реализовал. Остается узнать как блока по 4 новости сделать. Посмотрите на даты там не просто вывести такие то последние. Там числа разные могут идти 4 инюя 4 июня 4 июня 4 июня, а потом 3 июня 1 июня 31 мая 31 мая, например... хоть один пример покажите объясните

Comment: Ну сделай модуль который будет выводить именно ТЕ новости которые ты в нем укажиш например модуль выводит новость 4июня,3го апреля и тд тп

Comment: Спасибо. Додумал. Добавлю колонку к новостям типа shortnews и с этой пометкой буду выводить.. )) ) ) )